# Google Cloud SDK - how to call google apis or urls via internal gateway url?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-sdk

We are using google cloud sdk Python to fetch Crashes Data from BigQuery Tables. As per company policy, all outgoing internet traffic has to be routed through a centralized gateway.  However, we noticed that bigquery api is hardcoded in Python program. How can we externalize that endpoint so that calls will be made via this gateway rather than changing the program?

endpoint in the discussion is this:
https://bigquery.googleapis.com/upload/bigquery/v2/projects/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the api endpoint of BigQuery

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.api_core.client_options import ClientOptions
client_options = ClientOptions(api_endpoint="https://myNewEndpoint") 
client = bigquery.Client(project="myProject",client_options=client_options)
....
```